# packages have unmet dependencies - virtual box5.1 mysql-server

Tags: apt, virtualbox

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
 virtualbox-5.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 (>= 2:1.02.97) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                libgl1:i386
                       Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5core5a:i386 (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5gui5:i386 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                libqt5gui5-gles:i386 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5opengl5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                libqt5opengl5-gles:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5printsupport5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5widgets5:i386 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libqt5x11extras5:i386 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvpx3:i386 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcursor1:i386 (> 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmu6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libasound2:i386
                       Recommends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: linux-headers-generic:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                   linux-headers-generic-pae:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   linux-headers-686-pae:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   linux-headers-amd64:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   linux-headers-2.6-686:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   linux-headers-2.6-amd64:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   linux-headers:i386
                       Recommends: linux-image:i386
                       Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: binutils:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: pdf-viewer:i386
                       Recommends: libgl1:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: this is synaptic which i tried to install, similarly when i tried to install mysql as well it is throwing me dependencies error. please help me out with it

Comment: how to completely remove virtual box and start afresh or just remove it and fix the packages which are broken

Comment: Did you run  this `apt-get -f install`? And we see the command to install Virtualbox!

Comment: yes sir i tried and it tells me "graded, 160 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 57.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 320 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y"
then i pressed "Y" but its not proceeding ahead

Comment: ok do `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: thank you so much sir, its doneeeee finallyyyy...yes it happened with the later one..thanks a lott sir

Comment: Ok let me drop an answer so you can accept, :)

Answer (score 1):

From your conversation you need to update your repository index cache with the following lines and install what's required:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

With that `apt` should be able to get the required dependencies.